# How to drop duplicate records in the SQL Server using Python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I have a `.csv` file and it gets updated every day. Below is the example of my `.csv` file

[image]

I am pushing this `.csv` file into SQL Server using Python. My script reads the `.csv` file and uploads it into a SQL Server database.

This is my Python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

df = pd.read_csv ("C:/Users/Dhilip/Downloads/test.csv")

print(df)

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-7FCK7FG;'
                      'Database=test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE people_info (Name nvarchar(50), Country nvarchar(50), Age int)')

for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO test.dbo.people_info (Name, Country, Age)
                VALUES (?,?,?)
                ''',
                row.Name, 
                row.Country,
                row.Age
                )
conn.commit()
```

The script is working fine. I am trying to automate my Python script using batch file and task scheduler, and it's working fine. However, whenever I add new data in the `.csv` file and SQL Server gets updated with new data and the same time it prints the old data multiple times.

Example, if I add new record called Israel, the output appears in SQL Server as below

[image]

I need output as below,

[image]

Can anyone advise me the change I need to do in the above python script?

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicates, or only render/select your table without duplicates?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to remove all the duplicates. This data gets updated everyday in the excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query in your python script. **if Not exists** will check if the record already exists based on the condition in **where clause** and if record exists then it will go to else statement where you can update or do anything.

checking for existing records in database works faster than checking using python script.

```
if not exists (select * from Table where Name = '') 
begin
insert into Table values('b', 'Japan', 70)
end
else
begin
update Table set Age=54, Country='Korea' where Name = 'A'
end
```

to find existing duplicate records then use the below query

```
select Name, count(Name) as dup_count from Table
group by Name having COUNT(Name) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I find duplicates like this

```
def find_duplicates(table_name):
    """
    find duplicates inside table
    :param table_name:
    :return:
    """
    connection = sqlite3.connect("./k_db.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    findduplicates = """     SELECT  a.*
FROM {} a
JOIN (
SELECT shot, seq, lower(user), date_time,written_by, COUNT(*)
FROM {}
GROUP BY shot, seq, lower(user), date_time,written_by
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.shot = b.shot
AND a.seq = b.seq
AND a.date_time = b.date_time
AND a.written_by = b.written_by
ORDER BY a.shot;""".format(
        table_name, table_name
    )
    # print(findduplicates)
    cursor.execute(findduplicates)
    connection.commit()
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I am using sql server. Thanks for the code. I tried, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You could rephrase your insert such that it checks for existence of the tuple before inserting:

```py
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
        INSERT INTO test.dbo.people_info (Name, Country, Age)
        SELECT ?, ?, ?
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test.dbo.people_info
                          WHERE Name = ? AND Country = ? AND Age = ?)
    ''', (row.Name, row.Country, row.Age, row.Name, row.Country, row.Age,))

conn.commit()
```

An alternative to the above would be to add a unique index on `(Name, Country, Age)`.  Then, your duplicate insert attempts would fail and generate an error.